# How do I reference the brand color in inline (app specific) css on the index.html

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I have a habit of putting custom css that is app specific in the inline head `<style>` tags of index.html. This way I can adapt SAP defined classes differently across apps.

Is there a way to reference the brand color (and any other defined color) from the UI Theme that is used from within the inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the css class "sapBrandColor" or "sapUshellShellBrand"? However, according to the docs you should use "sapThemeBrand-asColor".

Here is the right documentation:

- [CSS Classes for Theme Parameters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/ea08f53503da42c19afd342f4b0c9ec7.html)
- [List of Supported CSS Classes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91a4946b0dcf4356aaaedc4e502864f4.html)